# Magento 2 : Change Comment of Onepage Checkout Email Address

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, onepage-checkout

I need to change this text in Magento 2 Checkout Onepage.
Please check in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to verify this things.

1. First, Check this file available into your custom theme.

   ```
   app/design/frontend/[THEME]/Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/form/element/email.html
   ```
2. Second, Check the same file overide into any custom extension.

   ```
   app/code/Vendor/Extension/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/form/element/email.html
   ```
3. Third, it call from default magento, So you need to overide same file either into your theme or any custom extenison and then make change into that.

Answer (score 1):

@Mayur you can override a core file to change that text vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/form/element/email.html .

if this does not work enable Debug hints from Store > configuration -> Developer debug section and check which file is rendering that text .